# Android APK to a streaming website

Tags: android

In my application I would like to stream a live video as im capturing with the camera on the phone. This stream should be sent to a website, like ustream or Justin.tv (or any one website). 
Do you guys know if its possible to do this via the code? 
Like an ustream APK to use or something.

Thanks!